# Case with Like operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Got stuck at using **CASE** statement with **LIKE** operator. In the below stored procedure all the parameters are not mandatory so when User doesn't enter PatientName for searching then the below query doesn't return expected results as the LIKE operator is outside which is obvious. I'm looking for something like this so that when User doesn't enter PatientName it will be

```
(c.LastName + c.Firstname) = @PatientNAme else 
(c.LastName + c.Firstname) like '%' + @PatientNAme + '%'

*

    (c.LastName + c.Firstname) (                          
        CASE @PatientName                          
          WHEN '' THEN @PatientName = (c.LastName + c.Firstname)                        
          ELSE  like '%' + @PatientName + '%'             
        END                          
    )  

*   

 CREATE proc [dbo].[SearchParkPrescriptionDetails]
    @DispenseID INT,
    @ParkPrescriptionReasonId INT,
    @PrescriptionParkType VARCHAR(50),
    @PatientName VARCHAR(120),
    @User VARCHAR(120),
    @fromdate DATETIME,
    @todate DATETIME,
    @DateWiseSearch VARCHAR(3),
    @PatientID INT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
          a.ParkPrescriptionId
        , a.DispenseID
        , a.ParkPrescriptionReasonId
        , a.ParkDate
        , (c.LastName + ' ' + c.Firstname) AS PatientName
        , d.PrescriptionType
        , e.ParkPrescriptionReason
        , a.Notes
        , b.ItemCount AS TotalItems
        , g.ExemptionReason
        ,a.[User]
    FROM
        ParkPrescriptionDetails a
        INNER JOIN
                Dis_DispenseMaster b
        ON
                a.DispenseID=b.DispenseID
        INNER JOIN
                Patient c
        ON
                b.PatientId = c.PatientId
        INNER JOIN
                Lookup_PrescriptionType d
        ON
                b.PrescriptionTypeId = d.PrescriptionTypeId
        INNER JOIN
                Lookup_ParkPrescriptionReason e
        ON
                a.ParkPrescriptionReasonId = e.ParkPrescriptionReasonId
        LEFT JOIN
                Lookup_ExemptionReason g
        ON
                b.ExemptionReasonId = g.ExemptionReasonId
    WHERE
        CONVERT(DATE, a.ParkDate) BETWEEN @fromdate AND @todate
        AND a.RecallStatus             = 'N'
        AND a.DispenseID               = ( CASE @DispenseID WHEN 0 THEN a.DispenseID ELSE @DispenseID END )
        AND b.PatientId                = ( CASE @PatientID WHEN 0 THEN b.PatientId ELSE @PatientID END )
        AND a.ParkPrescriptionReasonId = ( CASE @ParkPrescriptionReasonId WHEN 0 THEN a.ParkPrescriptionReasonId ELSE @ParkPrescriptionReasonId END )
        AND
        (
                c.LastName + c.Firstname
        )                     LIKE ( CASE @PatientName WHEN '' THEN (c.LastName + c.Firstname) ELSE '%' + @PatientName + '%' END )
        AND a.[User]          LIKE ( CASE @User WHEN '' THEN a.[User] ELSE '%' + @User + '%' END )
        AND b.ParkPrescription   = ( CASE @PrescriptionParkType WHEN '' THEN b.ParkPrescription WHEN 'Park' THEN 'Y' END )
        AND b.RecallPrescription = ( CASE @PrescriptionParkType WHEN '' THEN b.RecallPrescription WHEN 'Recall' THEN 'Y' END )
        AND a.IsDeleted          =0
END
```

========== Changed it Like this. Is this perfect ===========

---

```
(c.LastName + ' ' + c.Firstname) = (                          
        CASE @PatientName                          
          WHEN '' THEN  (c.LastName + ' ' + c.Firstname)                        
          ELSE   '%' + @PatientName + '%'             
        END                          
    )
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `CASE WHEN` in `where clause`. Use `OR`

```
 (
   @PatientName = '' OR 
   (c.LastName + c.Firstname) LIKE  '%' + @PatientName + '%'
 ) AND
 (
   @User = '' OR
   a.[User] LIKE  '%' + @User + '%' 
 ) -- Same for others
```

instead of

```
(c.LastName + ' ' + c.Firstname) = (                          
        CASE @PatientName                          
          WHEN '' THEN  (c.LastName + ' ' + c.Firstname)                        
          ELSE   '%' + @PatientName + '%'             
        END                          
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Will give it a try.

Comment: I just give you an example. You can change.

Answer (score 0):

T-SQL has two forms of CASE. You are using "Simple Case". Try "Searched Case" - e.g.:

```
CASE               
WHEN @PatientName = '' THEN [ return something ]
WHEN @PatientName like [ pattern ] THEN [ return something ]
ELSE [ return something else ]
END
```

Comment: Called 'Searched Case' vs 'Simple Case'

Comment: Thanks - included this in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion will try to implement.